# Java best practices: Re-declaring inherited interfaces?

Tags: java

I know that when a class extends another class, it will inherit all interfaces that it has implemented. In terms of best practices, does it make sense to declare again in subclass?

```
public interface LeggedCreature {
    public int getLegCount();
}

public abstract class Animal implements LeggedCreature {
    ...
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Override public int getLegCount() { return 4; }
}

public class MutatedDog extends Dog {
    @Override public int getLegCount() { return 6; }
}
```

Does that make more sense, or does the version below makes more sense?

```
public class MutatedDog extends Dog implements LeggedCreature {
    @Override public int getLegCount() { return 6; }
}
```

Comment: `@Override` will stop mistakes there so I don’t think you need to.

Comment: i think it is. declare interface will let user note that it's a implement of interfaces. this is more readable.

Comment: @yudongshen The Javadoc is the same whether you do or don't do this.